# What's a good library to do computational geometry (like CGAL) in a garbage-collected language?

Tags: python, binding, garbage-collection, computational-geometry, cgal

I need a library to handle computational geometry in a project, especially boolean operations, but just about every feature is useful.  The best library I can find for this is [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), but this is the sort of project I would hesitate to make without garbage collection.

What language/library pairs can you recommend?  So far my best bet is importing CGAL into D.  There is also a project for making Python bindings for CGAL, but it's very incomplete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would still recommend to proceed with Python and the existing Python binding. When you find it's incomplete, you'll also find that it is fairly easy to extend - Python's C API is designed so that integrating with external libraries is fairly easy (for experienced C programmers).

Comment: Yep, and look into one of the C++ bindings generators (which binds C++ code to python), such as SIP.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can look at Shapely for python

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/

For Java I would use JTS

For .NET I would use SharpMap or .NETTopologySuite

Answer (score 1):

The [CGAL-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) project provides bindings for CGAL using SWIG. The targeted languages, so far, are Java and Python. The CGAL-bindings project is open source, and supported/founded by two french companies.

Answer (score 0):

JTS is also available in .NET via IKVM.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this and it seems very promising even if it seems a young project: https://pyrr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#

> Pyrr is a Python mathematical library.

and it is based on numpy!