# CGAL for .Net ( or C#)

Tags: .net, cgal

I am not sure whether there is a .Net version of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org)? The last time I check there is only [one CGAL equivalent in garbage-collected language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517192/whats-a-good-library-to-do-computational-geometry-like-cgal-in-a-garbage-colle).

If would be tremendously helpful if we have CGAL.net.

*P/S: I know I can use interop, but still, a full managed version would be better.*

Comment: Depends on what you you need CGAL for - are you doing spatial operations. If so then you could look at
.NETTopologySuite or SharpMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no .Net version for CGAL.

Answer (score 3):

There is the open possibility of a C# wrapper... although the SWIG project for CGAL does NOT include C# at the moment, it has been requested.

https://github.com/cgal/cgal-swig-bindings/issues/3

> Are there plans to enable C# bindings for CGAL? Are there specific
> reasons for  not having enabled it yet?
> ...
>
> The main reason are time and resources. ... If someone experienced with C# wants to help,
> we probably can do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

There is a C# wrapper for a limited portion of CGAL:
https://github.com/martindevans/CGAL_StraightSkeleton_Wrapper

> CGAL_StraightSkeleton_Wrapper
>
> A C# wrapper around CGAL for calculating
>   straight skeletons of shapes. This is not and does not ever intend to
>   be a general C# wrapper around CGAL!

Answer (score 0):

It is a C++ library. Maybe it could be used through the .NET native code interop mechanisms?

Comment: I know I can use interop, but still, a full managed version would be better.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could **theoretically** try to do is to compile the C++ code as managed C++.
Not sure if it is **practically** easily doable though.

Comment: I tried this on other project.. no it didn't work that way because a lot of libraries are different

Comment: Maybe then it is time to start an .NET OSS project called NCGAL :)

Answer (score 0):

[CGALDotNet](https://github.com/Scrawk/CGALDotNet) is a wrapper to the C++ library.
It is limited in functionality and only supports Windows 64bit, but it is the best you can find right now.

The author stopped developing it mid 2022 though, so it's unlikely that it will evolve further.